# advanced permissions check boxes in nautilus missing

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gconf

I can't get the advanced permissions to show in nautilus. I checked the box /apps/nautilus/preferences/show-advanced-permissions in the configuration editor and it didn't change in nautilus. I'm still seeing the drop down version. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot

Answer (score 2):

While still shown in gconf nautilus settings are now  handled thru dconf. Install dconf-tools, then open dconf-editor & browse to org > gnome > nautilus > preferences

Or use gsettings, fairly logical

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-advanced-permissions true
```

Comment: Thanks doug. It doesn't show up in dconf org > gnome > nautilus > preferences but the gsettings method worked. I appreciate the help.